# What is the significance of m[1] in a Guardfile?

Tags: ruby, tdd, guard

From [Guardfile examples](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-examples):

```
watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb})    { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb})    { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
```

What do the values of `m` represent? It seems to be an array of length 2, storing the complete path and relative path...

How is `m` generated? Is it coming from Guard or Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m[1]` would be the first capture group in the regex match. And from the regex, that is the name of the file ( without the extension.)

This is actually explained in the README:

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end
```

> In this example the regular expression capture group (.+) is used to transform a file change in the lib folder to its test case in the spec folder. Regular expression watch patterns are matched with Regexp#match.

Answer (score 1):

m are the matches from the Regex.  See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-match  for more information.

Basiscally m[1] is used to get the name of the file that was matched, to run it corresponding spec.